# Automatic type-argument inference in scala

Tags: scala, type-inference, generic-type-argument

I tried to implement a function similar to:

```
def myMap[A,B](a: Seq[A], f: A => B): Seq[B] = a.map(f)

// then I want to call it like that:
myMap(List(1,13,42), _*2)
```

But the call to `myMap` doesn't compile because the compiler cannot infer the type arguments `A` and `B`. error: `missing parameter type`

Basically, I hoped that it would infer `A` (Int) given argument `List(1,13,42)` then infer `B` from given `f = _*2` knowing `A`. But it doesn't.

What could I do to avoid writing the type arguments?

The best I found was:

```
def myMap[A,B](a: Seq[A], f: A => B): Seq[B] = a.map(f)
myMap(List(1,13,42), (a: Int) => a*2)
```

I.e. I explicitly give `A` in the `f` argument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use multiple parameter lists.

```
def myMap[A,B](a: Seq[A])(f: A => B): Seq[B] = a.map(f)

// then call it like this:
myMap(List(1,13,42)) (_*2)
```

The collection api makes heavy use of this style for `foldLeft` and similar functions.
You can check the official style guide [here.](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html#multiple-parameter-lists)

Comment: I finally prefer my solution below. But yours answer better the question

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, using implicit class:

```
implicit class MyMap[A](a: A) {
  def myMap[B](f: A => B): B = f(a)
}

// then I can call
List(1,13,42).myMap(_*2)
```